# Android Studio hangs when I open any dialog box

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Android Studio(4.1.1) on Mac os Big Sur **in full screen mode** hangs whenever a new dialog box is opened. For example, If I open avd manager then the dialog box which is opened to choose the avd hangs and the whole window of android studio freezes. This only happens in full screen mode not in normal mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any lucks?